# How to handle ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature errors for ActiveStorage direct uploads

Tags: rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have a form where a user selects a file to upload. The file is uploaded once the file is selected using ActiveStorage direct uploads.  There is a submit button that is not clickable until the upload is complete.

The button is disabled when the form loads. However, if for some reason the user was able to click the button without first selecting a file I get the following error in my controller:

```
ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature - ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature:
```

I want to make sure my application is solid so I want to know how to deal with this error.

Here is my controller method:

```
def create
  authorize [:proofreaders, :proofread_document]
  @proofread_document = ProofreadDocument.build(proofread_document_params.merge(uploader: current_user, proofreading_job: @proofreading_job))
  if @proofread_document.save
    flash[:notice] = I18n.t('success.upload', resource: @proofread_document.file.filename)
    render :create, layout: false
  else
    render :new, layout: false
  end
end
```

My attempt to deal with this issue is to create my own 'build' method and use it instead  of the standard 'new' because 'new' raises the error in my controller and I want to deal with this in the model.

The 'build' method in my model:

```
  def self.build(params)
    pd = self.new params.except(:file)
    pd.file = params[:file]
    pd
  rescue ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature => e
    pd
  end
```

I have to separately assign the file attribute value to the model so the other attributes will get assigned before the error is raised.

This works as it returns the instance of the model that was setup before the error occurred and the validation of the file checks for an empty file value. However, is this really correct and is there a better way that more experienced and skilled developers are using?

Answer (score 1):

The way that I know how to solve this off the top of my head is to modify the params to reject blank values. for example

```
params[:user].delete(:avatar) if params[:user][:avatar].blank?
```

This works but it will make your controller action harder to look at I want to resolve this on the model side so Ill do that and fill you in how that turns out.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason this solved my problem.

```rb
  def user_params
    params.permit(
      :id, :name, :email, :username, :country, :avatar, :id_number, :license_number
    ).select {|x,v| v.present?}
  end
```

Looks like the empty value is causing the issue

```rb
 "id_number"=>"234545", "license_number"=>"234545", "avatar"=>""
```

---

My model

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :avatar
```